# Deep Snapshot in realm.js

Tags: react-native, realm

Is there any way to create a deep snapshot in realm.js. If not, is there a workaround to having my list objects decoupled from their proprietary objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not *yet* a way to do deep snapshots, but we are working towards that functionality. You can manually create copies of your objects when there are no reference cycles (i.e. a objects that link to each other in some way).